# All to win and to lose?

Tags: expressions, american-english

I read the sentence below in a book, but do not understand correctly the meaning.
Would you please let me know what it means?

```
"all to win yet and to lose of course"
```

Thanks

Comment: There should be a signalled pause: "all to win yet – and [you have all] to lose of course" / "all to win yet ... and to lose of course" / "all to win yet (and to lose of course)". << You could [at this moment go on to] win everything (in a situation; in life). But you _could_ lose everything you have at the moment. The venture in question is a gamble. >>  An example sentence:  'If you get carried away by some wild idea ... you have all to lose and nothing to gain.'...

Comment: ['Learning to Apply', Book 4; Quince Duncan](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=XwACVcZbtp8C&pg=PT52&lpg=PT52&dq=%22have+all+to+lose%22+meaning&source=bl&ots=APuWwFH7yr&sig=ACfU3U1w0tkkmVlNixEMpdlPtOx1q7DQpA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi6sYuRkvjsAhWqQEEAHZKVCskQ6AEwCHoECAwQAg#v=onepage&q=%22have%20all%20to%20lose%22%20meaning&f=false)